# 2012 Chrysler T&C - Exterior mirror questions

Tags: chrysler, town-and-country, mirrors

Back-story: I bought a used 2012 Chrysler Town and Country Touring-L. The driver side mirror was obviously damaged, so I returned the vehicle for warranty work to address that damage.

However, the newly installed part does not quite look like its passenger side twin. Either the new part is for a different model year, or the old part is also damaged.  Here are cropped images of the original passenger side (left) and new driver side (right) showing the turn signal indicator on the exterior side mirrors:

[image: passenger side]
[image: driver side]

Notice the driver side (right image) has a translucent cover, while passenger side (left image) does not.  It also seems like the new mirror is smaller, but that may just be an optical illusion.

Anyway, I dug around on [MOPAR](http://www.mopar.com/chrysler/town-and-country/2012/shop/335626/41/3107/) looking for a match, but not quite sure which part number I should be aiming for.  The numbers on the glass (GNTX0727150200 and GNTX0613122418, driver and passenger respectively) don't appear to match anything in the database.

Is there anyway to verify the new mirror assembly is the right part without removing the assembly from the door?  Can anyone comment on whether that passenger mirror assembly is missing its cover?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lens for the turn signal on the passenger mirror is missing

Comment: I would suggest the same.